# 2D Boolean Mask in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow problem that is probably easy.  I am trying to figure out how to do a 2D boolean_mask when my mask is 1D.  I have a 2D tensor `x` that has N X F dimensionality and a 1D tensor `mask` that has N dimensionality.  The `mask` contains 0s and 1s, and I want to keep the samples in `x` that have a `mask` value of 1.

```
threshold = tf.multiply(tf.ones_like(mask), 0.5)
mask = tf.greater(mask,threshold)
x = tf.boolean_mask(x,mask)
```

I get a value error because the shapes are incompatible.  Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: please mark your own answer as accepted

Answer (score 3):

Where `N` is the number of features I want to expand it to.

```
threshold = tf.multiply(tf.ones_like(mask), 0.5)
mask = tf.greater(mask,threshold)
x = tf.boolean_mask(x,tf.tile(mask,[1,N]))
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question or just a clarification?

Comment: It was the answer.  I figured it out after I submitted it.